# Can Exchange Transport Rule query a database or call a webservice?

Tags: exchange

Exchange newbie here...

Our customers belong to one of several service centers. We want to use just one email address when customers write to us. Customer emails should end up in the correct service center mailbox.

Is is possible to create a transport rule that looks the senders email up in a customer database (SQL Server) or call a webservice to resolve the correct mailbox or folder?

Comment: Have you thought of using a mailbox rule to accomplish that?

Comment: Thing is, we have about 300.000 customers so I don't think "static" mailbox rules are an option?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a proper CRM/service management product. That is not what Exchange is designed to do. 
You might get a custom transport agent written to do what you want, but Exchange natively isn't able to do it.